# What is principles of Domain Driven Design (DDD)?

Tags: domain-driven-design

What is principles of Domain Driven Design (DDD) with MediateR pattern  ? When should I use it , is it proper to use every type of project ?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Martin Fowler says:

> Domain-Driven Design is an approach to software development that centers the development on programming a domain model that has a rich understanding of the processes and rules of a domain.

So DDD is an approach about software development. You can choose DDD for your application and you implement all your code in this direction.

But mediator is a design pattern to solve specific software problems. You solve your a specific problem anywhere in your code. This is independent from your software development approach like singleton design pattern etc.

You can use mediator design pattern without DDD or you can use DDD without mediator. So there are no common principles between DDD and mediator design pattern.